# Merging dataframes with certain uncommon columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge ~300 dataframes. My constraint being, all of them have only 4 common columns and the rest may/may not be common. Which needs me to add columns to the dataframe everytime a new column is encountered during merging. 
I've simulated a toy dataset for the same.

Dataframe1:

```
Column_A : 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'd'
Column_CounterName : 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4', 'Type1'
Column_CounterValue : 100, 300, 356, 288, 233, 453
```

Dataframe2:

```
Column_A : 'm', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'o'
Column_CounterName : 'Type1', 'Type5', 'Type6','Type5', 'Type1'
Column_CounterValue : 100, 300, 356, 846, 7455
```

Merged Dataframe should be:

```
Column_A : 'a', 'b', 'd', 'm', 'n', 'o'
Type1 : 100, null, 453, 100, null, 7455
Type2 : 300, null, null, null, null, null
Type3 : null, 356, null, null null, null
Type4 : null, 233, null, null, null, null 
Type5 : null, null, null, 356, 846, null
Type6 : null, null, null, 356, null, null
```

Column_A, Type1, .... are all column names.

How do I do this ?

Also, how do I fill in the Null values after merging.

Comment: Is row `A` your headers?

Comment: yes & I've edited the same for convenience.

Comment: Wait your columns look like rows.  Can you just paste the result of `df.head` for your simple example?

Answer (score 1):

I believe need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for join all DataFrames by `A` column:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
#for each DataFrame create index by A column
dfs = [x.set_index('A') for x in dfs]
#for join by more columns
#dfs = [x.set_index(['A', 'col1', 'col2']) for x in dfs]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).rename_axis('A').reset_index()
print (df)
     A    B    D
0  'a'  1.0  NaN
1  'b'  2.0  NaN
2  'c'  3.0  NaN
3  'd'  4.0  NaN
4  'm'  NaN  's'
5  'n'  NaN  'd'
6  'o'  NaN  'k'
```

EDIT:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
#for each DataFrame create index by A column
dfs = [x.set_index(['Column_A','Column_CounterName']) for x in dfs]

df = pd.concat(dfs)['Column_CounterValue'].unstack().rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()
print (df)
  Column_A   Type1  Type2  Type3  Type4  Type5  Type6
0        a   100.0  300.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1        b     NaN    NaN  356.0  233.0    NaN    NaN
2        d   453.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3        m   100.0    NaN    NaN    NaN  300.0    NaN
4        n     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  846.0  356.0
5        o  7455.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

If get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means duplicates in pairs `Column_A` and `Column_CounterName` like:

```
d1 = {'Column_A' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'd'],
'Column_CounterName' : ['Type1', 'Type1', 'Type3', 'Type4', 'Type1'],
'Column_CounterValue' : [100, 300, 356,  233, 453]}

d2 = {'Column_A' :[ 'm', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'o'],
'Column_CounterName' : ['Type1', 'Type5', 'Type6','Type5', 'Type1'],
'Column_CounterValue' : [100, 300, 356, 846, 7455]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
print (df1)
  Column_A Column_CounterName  Column_CounterValue
0        a              Type1                  100 <- same a, Type1
1        a              Type1                  300 <- same a, Type1
2        b              Type3                  356
3        b              Type4                  233
4        d              Type1                  453

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
print (df2)
  Column_A Column_CounterName  Column_CounterValue
0        m              Type1                  100
1        m              Type5                  300
2        n              Type6                  356
3        n              Type5                  846
4        o              Type1                 7455
```

Then possible solution ias aggregate duplicated pairs, e.g. by `mean`:

```
df = (pd.concat(dfs)['Column_CounterValue']
        .groupby(level=[0,1])
        .mean()
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis(None, 1)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  Column_A   Type1  Type3  Type4  Type5  Type6
0        a   200.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN <- (100 + 300) / 2 = 200
1        b     NaN  356.0  233.0    NaN    NaN
2        d   453.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3        m   100.0    NaN    NaN  300.0    NaN
4        n     NaN    NaN    NaN  846.0  356.0
5        o  7455.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Yes that works fine. I have a more complex problem. Please help with that as well.

Comment: @user8241887 - add 2 possible solutions.